# Import class that imports Parse.com into Xcode's Prefix.pch generates error

Tags: ios, xcode5, parse-platform

I have a class that does logging throughout my iOS Xcode 5 app. Instead of importing it to every screen in my application I thought of simply putting it into my Prefix.pch file. So far so good - this works fine with my Util.h, and Constants.h files.

But my LoggingManager.h is importing the Parse.com framework, and for some reason the app doesn't compile.

These are the relevant lines of code from `LoggingManager`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "ActionLog.h"

@interface LoggingManager : NSObject
```

And this is the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocationManager", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFLocationManager.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why is this happening? Is there a solution? I should add that if I'm importing my LoggingManager directly into the other classes everything works fine, and also that my application is not location based and is no using the `CLLocationManager`.

Comment: Add the CoreLocation framework to your project.

Comment: Minor nitpick - your app does compile, it doesn't link.

Comment: Thanks, @rmaddy. Could you explain why is this working? I mean why do I need to import the CoreLocation framework when importing my LoggingManager through the Prefix.pch, while I don't need to do it when importing it directly in each class?

Comment: That makes no sense. It should need to link the framework either way.

Comment: That's what I thought. But it's the way it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the parse quickstart guide:

[image: parse]

Basically, import the CoreLocation.framework

Comment: Thanks, @JuJoDi. Could you explain why is this working? I mean why do I need to import the CoreLocation framework when importing my LoggingManager through the Prefix.pch, while I don't need to do it when importing it directly in each class?

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not entirely sure. I think it has to do with the way Xcode does its precompiling and the fact that everything in iOS has to be statically linked to a binary.  Xcode is probably 'smart' about linking but not when the classes are precompiled